# Why does the C-Gear flash red or green sometimes?

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-fifth-generation

In Pokemon Black and White, why does the online section of the C-Gear glow red or green sometimes? This seems to happen at random, even though I have a Wi-Fi connection.

Comment: if i'm not wrong it's just to call for attention...

Comment: @Michel Except that you can only use GameSync every 24 hours, so this couldn't possibly be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you are referring to the inside of the online part of C-GEAR, it
>   means:
>
> - If it's red you have a poor connection.
> - If it's blue you have a connection like the ones in gameshops.
> - if it's green you have a good conection.

[Source](http://pokemondb.net/pokebase/30539/c-gear-colors)

I tested it, and got only Green and red connections, the red sometimes made me disconnect.

I didn't found any Nintendo report about it (yet)

Comment: Thats odd then, because it says I have full bars (green) in the upper right corner, but the C-Gear is flashing red.